# Android/Xamarin Forms: Why isn't OnActivityResult firing for my camera intent?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, camera

I'm trying to have an Xamarin/Android app take a photo and send it to a server. I'm using Xamarin Forms and creating an Intent on the main activity.

What I expect to happen is that the camera appears, lets me take a photo, I get a chance to accept, reject or re-try the photo and if I accept or reject OnActivityResult gets called in my MainActivity and I can process the image data from there.

What's happening is that the overridden OnActivityResult function is never being called. The camera starts, I get to take a photo, confirm that it's OK, and then the screen stays on the camera and the calling app never regains control.

I'm starting the activity from the MainActivity, using StartActivityForResult:

```
            // ...
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "TakePhoto", (sender) => {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

                string file = String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
                PhotoData._file = new Java.IO.File(PhotoData._dir, file);

                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(PhotoData._file);
                intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uri);

                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            });
```

The "TakePhoto" message is sent from a button on a form, and the debugger confirms that it gets as far as calling StartActivityForResult. I'd expect this to fire when the camera takes a photo and the user confirms it.

I've overridded OnActivityResult in MainActivity.

```
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnActivityResult called");
        }
```

This isn't getting called at all. The debugger doesn't stop on a break point set here and the print message does not appear on the console.

A little googling suggests that this can happen if the MainActivity is in a TabHist (it's not) or if the Activity has NoHistory set to true. This is how I define the MainActivity class

```
    [Activity(
        Label = "SOC Operator",
        MainLauncher = true,
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash",
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        NoHistory = false)
    ]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        // ...
```

And that's about as far as can get by myself. The camera is called, the Intent fires, but the handler is never called and control never returns to my app.

I **do** get an error in the output where it says the camera

`D/Camera  (26290): app passed NULL surface`

but that seems to happen before the Intent is created, and in any case, the camera part of the process seems to work just fine.

Comment: You can use the plugin `Media.Plugin` .Check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that. This is a bit of a frankenstien of an app in the first place, and I was hoping to avoid adding another way of doing things. What it really needs is a ground up refactor, but I don't think I have time for that.

Comment: You just need to call the method in forms if using the plugin .

Comment: Yep. I seem to have it working now. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: What exactly did you do to solve this issue, I've started seeing it in on some of the device I've released our APP to but not all of them and its confusing the shit out of me :p